# Using/Filtering raw live data using the "grep" command with the "while-read" loop

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, grep

Goal: Filter raw live data using the `grep` command. I would like the to provide the user with a filter tag "-f" that will allow them to filter the data that is coming based on their own input to the terminal

Issue: Although the `grep` command seems to be running in the script without issue, BUT it doesn't seem to be actively filtering each element of the file line by line as the `while` loop reads in the data

the code I have thus far is as follows:

```
maxbar=60 # largest no. of char in the bar
MAX=60

while read dayst timst qty
do
        if ! [[ -z $FILTER ]] # FILTER flag starts process                                              
        then

             grep "200510" tailcount.sh
             printf '%6.6s %6.6s %4d:' $dayst $timst $qty
             pr_bar $qty $MAX

        fi

        printf '%6.6s %6.6s %4d:' $dayst $timst $qty
        pr_bar $qty $MAX

done < <( if ! [[ -z $ON ]]; then bash killswitch.sh; elif [[ -z $ON ]] ; then bash tailcount.sh; fi )
```

Comment: Please provide more of the script around this code block.  (We need to understand the while-loop.)

Comment: Yeah I just now noticed this, should I just repost the question with more code included?

Comment: Nope.  Just edit your original question.  Stack Overflow is mutable!